# How to conditionally SetProperty with Entity Framework Core ExecuteUpdate?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

When querying a database with EF Core, it's easy to conditionally add `.Where` clauses to a query before executing the query, e.g.:

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<List<Entity>> GetEntitiesAsync(string? property1, string? property2)
{
    var query = _context.Entities.AsNoTracking();
    if (property1 != null)
    {
        query = query.Where(e => e.Property1.Contains(property1));
    }
    if (property2 != null)
    {
        query = query.Where(e => e.Property2.Contains(property2));
    }
    return await query.ToListAsync();
}
```

However, when using `.ExecuteUpdate`, I can't see how you would conditionally chain `.SetProperty` clauses:

```
[HttpPatch("{id}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> UpdateEntityAsync(int id, Entity entity)
{
    var entitiesUpdated = await _context.Entities
        .Where(e => e.Id == id)
        .ExecuteUpdateAsync(s => s
            // How to conditionally chain SetProperty based on
            // if entity.Property1 and entity.Property2 are null?
            .SetProperty(e => e.Property1, entity.Property1)
            .SetProperty(e => e.Property2, entity.Property2)
    );

    return entitiesUpdated == 1 ? NoContent() : NotFound();
}
```

You can't use `if` statements inside the lambda. It needs to be a single expression that evaluates to a `SetPropertyCalls<T>`. Maybe you could manually create an expression tree, but wouldn't you need to build it on top of the parameter passed into the lambda? Is there an easy way I'm not seeing?

Comment: I created an issue for this on GitHub: https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/32018

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`SetProperty` allows passing expression to calculate the value. To dynamically combine `SetProperty` calls based on condition you can use [ternary conditional operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/conditional-operator) :

```
var entitiesUpdated = await _context.Entities
    .Where(e => e.Id == id)
    .ExecuteUpdateAsync(s => s
         .SetProperty(e => e.Property1, e => entity.Property1 != null
              ? entity.Property1
              : e.Property1)
         .SetProperty(e => e.Property2, , e => entity.Property2 != null
              ? entity.Property2
              : e.Property2));
```

Though this will generate SQL like `"PropertyX" = "e"."PropertyX"` for cases when the source is `null`.

A bit harder but more "correct" approach to perform "conditional" batch update is to perform some [expression trees manipulation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/advanced-topics/expression-trees/):

```cs
// helper method to combine set expressions
static Expression<Func<SetPropertyCalls<TEntity>, SetPropertyCalls<TEntity>>> AppendSetProperty<TEntity>(
    Expression<Func<SetPropertyCalls<TEntity>, SetPropertyCalls<TEntity>>> left,
    Expression<Func<SetPropertyCalls<TEntity>, SetPropertyCalls<TEntity>>> right)
{
    var replace = new ReplacingExpressionVisitor(right.Parameters, new []{left.Body});
    var combined = replace.Visit(right.Body);
    return Expression.Lambda<Func<SetPropertyCalls<TEntity>, SetPropertyCalls<TEntity>>>(combined, left.Parameters);
}

// empty set expression
Expression<Func<SetPropertyCalls<Author>, SetPropertyCalls<Author>>> set = 
     calls => calls;

// conditionally append set for Property1 
if (entity.Property1 is not null)
{
    set = AppendSetProperty(set,
          s => s.SetProperty(e => e.Property1, entity.Property1));
}

// conditionally append set for Property2
if (entity.Property2 is not null)
{
    set = AppendSetProperty(set,
          s => s.SetProperty(e => e.Property2, entity.Property2));
}
```

Comment: This technically works, but it ends up generating SQL like this:
`UPDATE "Entities" AS "e"
SET "Property1" = @__Property1
    "Property2" = "e"."Property2"
WHERE "e"."Id" = @__id`
Every column is either set to the new value or set to itself. Is there a way so only the columns to be changed are set?

Comment: @HanyouHottie Sorry. Misunderstood the question, it is other way around, it's not database fields you need to check. Yes, it is, but will require expression tree manipulation. Will update the question in an hour or so.

Comment: Second approach does not work. In lines like `s => s.SetProperty(e => e.Property1, entity.Property1)` `e` is not a entity and does not contain `Property1`

Comment: @Niksr yes it does) I have tested it myself and it clearly worked for OP. Can you please share a [mre] showing the problem (for example at github)

Comment: You right, it works. I moved your  `AppendSetProperty` into static method and must be made a mistake. Sorry and thank you for a great solution.

Comment: Can you provide a working example on how to use the second approach along with ExecuteUpdate. I couldn't really understand how it works.

Comment: @Adnan it should sufficient enough. Basically you build the set expression (similar to how you can build predicate for `Where`) and then call `.ExecuteUpdateAsync(set)`. If you have question I can try to create a full blown [mre] later but not sure when I will have time.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a simple helper I wrote that composes the expression tree "transparently" and enables these kinds of scenarios — while allowing you to use the same API shape, unlike Guru Stron's answer:

Usage:

```cs
int affectedCount = await dbContext.Books
    .Where(b => b.Id == someBookId)
    .ExecutePatchUpdateAsync(b =>
    {
        if (someCondition)
            b.SetProperty(b => b.Foo, "Foo");
        else
            b.SetProperty(b => b.Bar, "Bar");
    });
```

The implementation:

```cs
public static class QueryableExecutePatchUpdateExtensions
{
    public static Task<int> ExecutePatchUpdateAsync<TSource>(
        this IQueryable<TSource> source,
        Action<SetPropertyBuilder<TSource>> setPropertyBuilder,
        CancellationToken ct = default
    )
    {
        var builder = new SetPropertyBuilder<TSource>();
        setPropertyBuilder.Invoke(builder);
        return source.ExecuteUpdateAsync(builder.SetPropertyCalls, ct);
    }

    public static int ExecutePatchUpdate<TSource>(
        this IQueryable<TSource> source,
        Action<SetPropertyBuilder<TSource>> setPropertyBuilder,
    )
    {
        var builder = new SetPropertyBuilder<TSource>();
        setPropertyBuilder.Invoke(builder);
        return source.ExecuteUpdate(builder.SetPropertyCalls);
    }
}

public class SetPropertyBuilder<TSource>
{
    public Expression<Func<SetPropertyCalls<TSource>, SetPropertyCalls<TSource>>> SetPropertyCalls { get; private set; } = b => b;

    public SetPropertyBuilder<TSource> SetProperty<TProperty>(
        Expression<Func<TSource, TProperty>> propertyExpression,
        TProperty value
    ) => SetProperty(propertyExpression, _ => value);

    public SetPropertyBuilder<TSource> SetProperty<TProperty>(
        Expression<Func<TSource, TProperty>> propertyExpression,
        Expression<Func<TSource, TProperty>> valueExpression
    )
    {
        SetPropertyCalls = SetPropertyCalls.Update(
            body: Expression.Call(
                instance: SetPropertyCalls.Body,
                methodName: nameof(SetPropertyCalls<TSource>.SetProperty),
                typeArguments: new[] { typeof(TProperty) },
                arguments: new Expression[] {
                    propertyExpression,
                    valueExpression
                }
            ),
            parameters: SetPropertyCalls.Parameters
        );

        return this;
    }
}
```

Comment: Does not compile, syntax error in line `Action<SetPropertyBuilder<TSource>> setPropertyBuilder`

Answer (score -1):

This method works for me in my MAUI .NET 7 proyect:
On my `TryLogin()` method I use the line `await Constants.UpdateEntityAsync(_context, data);` for dynamic update

```
    var TokenResult = await _loginService.LoginBusiness(UserValue,PassValue, AliasValue);

    if (TokenResult != null && TokenResult.token != null)
    {

        UtilDataModel data = await _context.UtilData.FirstAsync();

        data.token = TokenResult.token;
        data.expiration = TokenResult.expiration;
        data.businessId = TokenResult.businessId;
        data.userId = TokenResult.userId;
        data.depositId = TokenResult.depositId;
        data.apiVersion = TokenResult.apiVersion;
        data.empresa = TokenResult.empresa;
        data.nombreUsuario = UserValue;
        data.basedatos = TokenResult.basedatos;

        await Constants.UpdateEntityAsync(_context, data);
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
else
{
    await Shell.Current.DisplayAlert("Error", "Debe escribir sus datos para ingresar!!", "ok");
    return false;
}
```

}

And here in a static class I put the generic method to do dynamic update:

Generic method:

[image: Generic method]

Then with this code now I can use the generic method to update any object

Comment: Your answer does nothing with the question. `ExecueUpdate` is  a "new" performant way to update values in tables without retrieving entitles in advance.  It's rough equivalent of raw SQL requests. In your answer you use traditional (in terms of EF) way to first retrieve and then update entity.  The difference is performance:  `ExecueUpdate` is 10x faster.