# call a function within EF Core's ExecuteUpdate() method?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, npgsql, .net-7.0, ef-core-7.0

I want to do this in order to have a predefined list of properties to update that I can add onto. For instance, when i want to  update a property of some entities, i want to update the specific property AND a predefined list of audit properties (like a datetime column called UpdatedOn)

So, for example, I want to make updates to entities using the following code:

```
currentContext.myEntities
.Where( some logic )
.ExecuteUpdate(e => myFunction(e)
.SetProperty( additional set property statements));
```

where an example of the function is something like:

```
public static Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.SetPropertyCalls<T> myFunction<T>(Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.SetPropertyCalls<T> call,DateTime timestamp)
            where T:AuditableEntity
{
     //return a setPropertyCall with one or more SetProperty statements attached
     return call.SetProperty(e => e.UpdatedOn, e=>timestamp);
}
```

Is this possible, is there something im missing? When i try this, i get an error at runtime that says ExecuteUpdate can only have setProperty calls inside it (which i assume means i can't have that function i list above)

If Function might not be the right approach, is there a way to programmatically create a SetPropertyCalls chain?

For Specificity, i get the error:

> could not be translated. Additional information: The
> 'setPropertyCalls' argument to 'ExecuteUpdate' may only contain a
> chain of 'SetProperty' expressing the properties to be updated.

Comment: An alternative I can accept is something that builds the SetPropertyCalls object before hand so i can use that prebuilt SetPropertyCall in ExecuteUpdate

Comment: Suggest not adding comments but perhaps "notes" in the question to enhance clarity; and  can format better etc.

Answer (score 0):

You could use interceptors added in EF Core 7 which was release last November 2022:
https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/announcing-ef7-preview7-entity-framework/

Or you can chain the SetProperty:

```
.ExecuteUpdate(p => p.SetProperty(x => x.LastName, x => "Updated" + x.LastName).SetProperty(x => x.FirstName, x => "Updated" + x.FirstName));
```

Or if it needs to be conditional you can create an expression tree:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/advanced-topics/expression-trees/

[How to conditionally SetProperty with Entity Framework Core ExecuteUpdate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75924095/how-to-conditionally-setproperty-with-entity-framework-core-executeupdate)

Comment: Does this work with ExecuteUpdate, i was under the impression that ExecuteUpdate goes around normal context things

Comment: I can't find a way to implement an interceptor for ExecuteUpdate

Comment: @DanielGoldberg I have updated my answer with a couple more options. The last one I think is what you are looking for.