# How to pass multiple values to SetPropertyCalls for ExecuteUpdate in EF 7

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core, lambda, expression

I have the following query:

```
           IQueryable<Location> query = unitOfWork.LocationRepository.Query()
                .Where(x => x.ID == "{some-id}");
```

I want to update the Location properties with values:

```
            List<(Func<Location, object>, object)> parameters = new List<(Func<Location, object>, object)>
            {
                (x => x.Name, "New Name"), // string
                (x => x.Date, DateTime.Now) // DateTime
            };
```

How to build SetProperty dynamically from the list above?

```
            query.ExecuteUpdate(sett => sett.SetProperty(... here??? ...));
```

I started with simple:

```
Func<Location, string> func = x => x.Name;

            query.ExecuteUpdate(sett => sett.SetProperty(func, "abc123"));
```

But this fails and I get System.InvalidCastException: 'Unable to cast object of type 'System.Linq.Expressions.TypedParameterExpression' to type 'System.Linq.Expressions.LambdaExpression'.'

When I use lambda directly:

```
// This works
query.ExecuteUpdate(sett => sett.SetProperty(x => x.Name, "abc123"));
```

**So how to pass multiple Func<> to the SetProperty?**

Update 7/7: Context added:

I am creating an extension method to improve the performance of the app.
Instead of loading entity, changing single property and saving it I want to set property value and save it quickly with EF7 ExecuteUpdate().
There is some logic implemented in DbContext.SaveChanges() which updates the entity when saving (setting current user name, last updated time, ...) and I want the same for ExecuteUpdate().
I expect several properties to be saved in the same time (max. 5 to have it efficient), that's why I need a List.

```
public static async Task<int> ExecuteUpdateCustom<T, V>(this IQueryable<T> source,
    List<(Func<T, V> propertyExpression, V value)> propertiesAndValuesSet) where T : class
{
    if (source is IHasUserDetails)
    {
        List<(Func<T, V>, V)> parameters = new List<(Func<T, V>, V)>
        {
            (x => x.UpdatedBy, getCurrentUser()),
            (x => x.ModifiedTime, DateTime.UtcNow)
        };

        // Chain
        propertiesAndValuesSet.AddRange(parameters);
    }

    return await source.ExecuteUpdateAsync(setters => setters.SetProperty(...propertiesAndValuesSet...));
}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate why you need to create the updates separately like that in a list instead of just passing the expressions directly in the call?

Comment: What's the actual  problem you try to solve with this? Explain the actual problem, not how you thought to solve it. EF doesn't need "repositories" or "units of work" it's already both. It doesn't need to be made generic, everything is already generic. You *can't* pass a client-side function to a LINQ expression or batch operation. Those aren't functions, they're generic *expressions* that get translated to SQL. The `ExecuteUpdate` docs show how you can [update multiple properties by chaining SetProperty operations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/saving/execute-insert-update-delete)

Comment: `When I use lambda directly:` that's not a lambda, that's an [a very specific expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.relationalqueryableextensions.executeupdate?view=efcore-7.0) builder, meant to make it easy to create an `UPDATE` query through a fluent API. If you don't want to use the fluent API you'll have to construct that entire expression. You could try to use VS or Resharper's `Extract Variable` refactoring to extract a multi-property expression into a variable, to see what the syntax and types would look like

Comment: Note that you should probably be using `Expression<Func<T, U>>` and not `Func<T, U>` directly.

Comment: julealgon, @Panagiotis Kanavos, DavidG I added more context what I need, see my updated question.

Comment: `ExecuteUpdateAsync` doesn't call `SaveChanges`, it *bypasses* it, generates an `UPDATE` SQL from the properties and executes it immediately. There are no objects for `SaveChanges` to work on, no changes to detect.

Comment: `that's why I need a List.` you don't need a list if you know the properties involved in advance. `SetProperty` calls are meant to be chained, just like LINQ operators. If you know the properties, you can write the chain and then extract the entire expression into a variable so you can reuse it. You could write a loop that chains `SetProperty` calls the same way you would with `Where` *but* the signature is very big and ugly.

Comment: BTW if you really care about the audit properties it's better to record them in the database itself using triggers or using a temporal table. Even better, record the business event explicitly. If you want to find modified rows, Change Tracking in SQL Server will return the changed rows. Audit columns are a quick&dirty way to handle auditing but definitely not the easier to actually operate

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can declare the list like this

```cs
List<Expression<Func<SetPropertyCalls<TSource>, SetPropertyCalls<TSource>>>> parameters = new()
{
    { sett => sett.SetProperty(x => x.Name, "New Name") }, // string
    { sett => sett.SetProperty(x => x.Date, DateTime.Now) }, // DateTime
};
```

Combining them is a little tricky. you essentially need to manufacture a new `Expression` for each of those, which does `return firstExpression(secondExpression);`

I think the following code should work:

```cs
Expression<Func<SetPropertyCalls<TSource>, SetPropertyCalls<TSource>>> CombineSetters(
    IEnumerable<Expression<Func<SetPropertyCalls<TSource>, SetPropertyCalls<TSource>>>> setters
)
{
    Expression<Func<SetPropertyCalls<TSource>, SetPropertyCalls<TSource>>> expr = sett => sett;

    foreach (var expr2 in setters)
    {
        var call = (MethodCallExpression)expr2.Body;
        expr = Expression.Lambda<Func<SetPropertyCalls<TSource>, SetPropertyCalls<TSource>>>(
            Expression.Call(expr.Body, call.Method, call.Arguments),
            expr2.Parameters
        );
    }

    return expr;
}
```

You can then do

```cs
await source.ExecuteUpdateAsync(finalExpression);
```

Comment: great answer, however The LINQ expression 'DbSet<Location>()
    .Where(l => __request_IDs_0.Contains(l.LocationID))
    .ExecuteUpdate(sett => sett.SetProperty<string>(
        propertyExpression: x => x.Name, 
        valueExpression: "New Name").SetProperty<bool>(
        propertyExpression: x => x.Used, 
        valueExpression: True))' could not be translated. Additional information: The 'setPropertyCalls' argument to 'ExecuteUpdate' may only contain a chain of 'SetProperty' expressing the properties to be updated.

Comment: That's weird, because it looks exactly as it's supposed to. I made some changes, please see updated answer. Or what about using the `AppendSetProperty` function from this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/75924143/14868997 to combine the expressions?

Comment: That's what I meant the code would be very complicated, but this is actually even *more* complicated than I expected.

Comment: True, it's to do with the way the setters are called with fluent syntax, which is difficult to combine. But sometimes it's useful to be able to abstract out certain setters across many tables, for example an `UpdateByUser` or `UpdatedDate` column.