# EF Core 7: How To Use ExecuteUpdateAsync Without Manually Specifying Fields and Values

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

Using EF Core 7, I can update object directly against DB using new API `ExecuteUpdateAsync`.

It has one problem; I need to manually specify the fields that need to be updated with values. So I'm looking for a way to use it in similar way when using `automapper` to create new object.

For example, I can manually do this:

```cs
DataContext.Books.Where(x => x.Id == dto.Id)
  .ExecuteUpdateAsync(x => x
    .SetProperty(z => z.Title, dto.Title)
    .SetProperty(z => z.AuthorId, dto.AuthorId
  )
  ;
```

but I'm looking for a way to automatically assign these values without having to call `SetProperty` manually for each field in `dto`.

Comment: This answer might be a good start https://stackoverflow.com/a/75924143/14868997 combine that with some reflection and `MakeGenericMethod` etc